# How to Custom Authorization from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

Normally use authorization settings to interact with the roles.

```
<location path="Register.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

But I would like to have this setup in the database in a table

```
tblAuthorization
-IdAuthorization (Identy(1,1))
-IdCompany=5
-IdRol=5 (Administrator”)
-Path=”Register.aspx”
```

Is there a setting for a class to do this? There is something like Profile, RoleProvider ..

```
<roleManager enabled="true"  defaultProvider="MyAccessRolProvider">
   <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MyAccessRolProvider" type="MyAccessRolProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
      <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Right now the only I think that can to implement a validation in the Page_Load event
And if it is invalid making a Redirect but I would do a little more "Professional"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      if(!ValidateAuthorization())
      {
          Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
      }
   }
}
```

Could help me with examples?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to implement a custom RoleProvider - you seem to be heading in this direction as your question includes a configuration section with a custom RoleProvider (MyAccessRolProvider).

You need to specify the fully-qualified name of your RoleProvider, e.g. `MyNamespace.MyAccessRoleProvider, MyAssembly`.

[MSDN describes how to do this, including a sample implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box support for this as far as I know however I would suggest you implement something as follows:

Create a new class that derives from AuthorizeAttribute, add an ID property and override the "AuthorizeCore" method.

```
  public class CustomAutorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            public Guid ActionId { get; set; }

            protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                //Check user has access to action with ID = ActionId
                //implementation omitted
            }
        }
```

You can add a new database table to hold on the Actions and their associated ID values. You can either add the record to the table manually or write some code to do this using reflection (I would advise this if you have quite a few actions and are likely to add more in the future).

Once this is done you can assign users or application roles access to these actions.

In you custom Authorize attribute you have to check whether the user has access to the given action returning true or false accordingly from the AuthorizeCore method.

I would advise grabbing a collection of all actions a user has access to when a user logs in and storing them in either the server cache or some kind of distributed cache so that you aren't hitting your database on every request.

UPDATE - Sorry just realised you're using ASP.NET Forms and not MVC. My approach is for an MVC application so its probably not relevant although I'll leave it up here in case any MVC developers happen to stumble across your question.

Answer (score 0):

With the understanding that you are taking about authorization at the page level you could add a HTTP module ([IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx)) and use your module to do the authorization checking.  If the authorization failed then you could redirect as appropriate.

Something like this might work:

```
public class MyAuthorizationModule : IHttpModule
{

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.AuthorizeRequest += (new EventHandler(AuthorizeRequest));
    }

    private void AuthorizeRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = //your code here to check page authorization

        if (!isAuthorized) 
        {  
            var response = //will need to get current response
            response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget you'll need to add the module to your web application.